# stm32 fatfs library from system workbench for stm32

Tags: c++, stm32

I have a problem with STM32. I use System Workbench For STM32 and I inclue to my project Hal and FatFs (when I create a project I choose it). But after create a project have error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type 'PPP_OK' undeclared (first use
>   in this
>   function) ppp_diskio_template.c   /Hal_sd/Middlewares/Third_Party/FatFs/src/drivers   line
>   98    C/C++ Problem

How can I build it? I want make an example project with FatFs but I can't build empty `main.c`.

Comment: Did you use Cube to generate the project? Which destination did you choose for the FAT FS?

Answer (score 0):

I see you mention `ppp_diskio_template.c`.

FatFs is just a way to organize data on a storage, and access them via a "file abstraction". FatFs shows you "files", but at then end it's just bytes stored in a storage.

The diskio template is a file with some functions that you need to define so that the FatFs can read/write to the storage. Basically, it's the functions that FatFS will use to store the data "as bytes" when you provide a file.

The fact that `PPP_OK` is not defined means that perhaps `ppp_diskio_template.h` or `ppp_diskio.h` is unavailable, not at the right place or not included in the files of your project.

You can basically search it in all the `.h` you have to see which one you need to include.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Solution:** If you are using STM32CubeMX or STM32CubeIDE, you should enable FatFS under `Pinout & Configuration > Categories > Middlewares > FATFS`. CubeMX handles the rest, you should be fine. Make sure you are using the latest version.

**2nd Solution:** If you are manually adding FatFS files, make sure to add all `.h` files into you include path, which is located in `Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes` if your IDE is Eclipse or STM32CubeIDE.

**3rd Solution:** Another possibility is that if you are trying to manually fork an example, this happens most of the times. Search the folder in Windows Explorer using the search box in upper right corner of the corresponding folder window for the variable that is not found which is in your case `PPP_OK`. Then find the variable where it's declared. This is generally a `.c` file, if so, make sure to add it to your project, also find the same named `.h` file and add its location to you include path as described in 2nd solution.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think the header file was added to your project.